# Redirect domain to subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to hosting a website. At my host i can create a lot of subdomains.
At the moment my main page is under construction so i would like to make it go to my subdomain which is finished.

Now i've heard some things about redirecting a domain to a subdomain with the .htaccess file.
I've located my .htaccess file at:

```
/cgi-bin/.htaccess
```

So i thought it's just adding this line:

```
Redirect 301 / http://Subdomain.domain.nl/
```

and then it'll redirect too bad it doesn't somehow.
How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the rule is being applied? is `/cgi-bin/` the root directory of your domain?

Comment: In my root there is my site which is under construction. The /cgi-bin/ folder is within my root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://Subdomain.domain.nl/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked out :) So everything i want to have access to in my root needs to be done in the htaccess file within my root, instead of cgi-bin? (will accept answere when i'm able to)!

Comment: Yes all that code should be in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` only.

Answer (score 0):

Hi mate I have found this way very easy. Go to the main domain if that's not the one you are using.

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; url=http://www.subdomain.domain.tld">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Very easy and with no issues that I have found and better than person going to a UC website.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is the most easy way that's true, but it's not that quite beautiful though :P